# Automatically scroll RecyclerView horizontally

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm showing a list of items in recyclerview which has horizontal orientation. Now i want to scroll the recyclerview automatically when it is loaded with items and also it should continue like a loop. How can i achieve this mechanism.

Comment: Check scrollToPosition() function of recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Use handle for this

```
final int speed = 5000; // delay time 
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
int count = 0;
boolean flag = true;
@Override
public void run() {
    if(count < adapter.getItemCount()){
        if(count==adapter.getItemCount()-1){
            flag = false;
        }else if(count == 0){
            flag = true;
        }
        if(flag) count++;
        else count--;

        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
        handler.postDelayed(this,speed);
    }
   }
   };

 handler.postDelayed(runnable,speed);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**,If you want a loop, you can override the recyclerview adapter `getItemCount()` and return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

**Second**,If you only want scroll.you can get the Butt's anwser for reference.
However,If you want scroll smooth. Luckily.The Recyclerview support it ,you can see 
the LayoutManager `smoothScrollToPosition()`,you can custom your `SmoothScroller` or for a reference with `LinearSmoothScroller`